# Update items within php objects

Tags: php, silverstripe

I want to update the `Content` string within the object. With the first foreach I get this:

```
object(Page)#1716 (20) {
        ["_cache_statusFlags":protected]=> NULL
        ["creatableChildrenCache":protected]=> NULL
        ["destroyed"]=> bool(false)
        ["record":protected]=> array(22) {
          ["ClassName"]=> string(4) "Page"
          ["ID"]=> int(1)
          ["ParentID"]=> int(0)
          ["Title"]=> string(5) "Home"
          ["MenuTitle"]=> NULL
          ["URLSegment"]=> string(4) "home"
          ["Content"]=> string(2210) "
My content that needs to be updated
"...
```

I tried with json_decode, (array) but I either get "Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Page as array" or no error and no update.

```
// json_decode($results,true);
foreach ($results as $result) {
   json_decode($result,true); // seem like it does nothing
   // tried (array)$result['record']['Content'], (array)$result['Content'],...
   // $result['Content'] = str_replace($keywords,'<span class="highlight-search">' .$keywords . '</span>',$result->Content);
   $result['record']['Content'] = str_replace($keywords,'<span class="highlight-search">' .$keywords . '</span>',$result->Content);
}
```

I also tried with foreach($result as $key => $field)...

At this point I'm just guessing. What is the proper procedure?

Comment: Its an object, not a json string, but it an object with protected properties

Comment: `json_decode($result,true); // seem like it does nothing`...well 1) $result seemingly isn't a JSON string, and 2) even if it was, you're not capturing the output of it, so of course you won't see anything useful from it. Try [reading the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: `With the first foreach I get this`...what actual line of code outputs that? I don't see anything in your code which would output anything.

Comment: This is not actually a duplicate - the question which was linked to ignores the fact that Silverstripe has some magic going on for its db fields.

You can just go `$this->Content = '<p>This is my content</p>';` to set the Content, or `$myContent = $this->Content;` to get the content.

Obviously replace `$this` with the variable holding the `DataObject` if you're accessing it externally.